# how to protecte .net application of cracking

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

i work on an application , my application read serial number's a device , i want check the

serial number and my application work just with this device and does not work with other device 
how do i encrypte and check this serial number that my application is not crackeable??

thanks

Comment: you can not 100% secure your code , a hacker who wants to circumvent your check , will eventually succeed but you can only make her life rock hard with placing high security checks

Answer (score 1):

This will be hard for .NET application. Mainly because you need to distribute it in MSIL, that is easily reverse-compiled into any other .NET language.

You can use one of many obfuscators (either free or comercial), that basicaly reshufles your code around making it almost unreadable for humans. But tools are still able to get hold of it and de-obfuscate it.

But remember, if your app is worth cracking, it will be cracked no matter what protection you use and what language or framework you use. Only "good enough" solution is hardware key.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. You can use a code obfuscater, but .net code is still easily reversible.

And of course even if you wrote it in native code, client side code can can **always** be cracked.